# Create a mapped RDD and save it in text

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark, distributed-computing, apache-spark-mllib

I runned a K-means example and I have an RDD with my data named parsedData
and my model named clusters. I want to create a mapped Rdd with datapoint and prediction cluster from the model. So I tried

```
val predictions = parsedData.map( point => 
{
val pointPred = clusters.predict(point) 
Array(point,pointPred)
})
```

when I try

```
 predictions.first()
```

I take

> Array[Any] = Array([0.8898668778942382,0.89533945283595], 0)

which is the result I want. So then I tried

```
predictions.saveAsTextFile ("/../ClusterResults");
```

to save The Arrays from each datapoint in a local file but the file created was

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@3b43c55c
>
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@5e523969
>
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@68374cdf ....

had the objects and not the data. I also tried to print from the RDD like

```
predictions.take(10).map(println)
```

and took the objects as a result again.
How can I take the data and not the objects and save them to a local file?

Comment: Use `predictions.saveAsTextFile`.

Comment: Also, you need to `mkString` those arrays

Comment: Soory I edited my code I did us saveAsTextFile and took Ljava.lang.Object;@3b43c55c ....

Comment: Don't use an array, then. Use a Tuple

Comment: In my map? Like .map( point =>(point, cluster.predict(point)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you map your data. Try using a *Tuple*, instead of an *Array*.

Example:

```
val predictions = parsedData.map( point => {
  (point, clusters.predict(point))
})
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this and worked. But my question still lies why first() prints the Array and not the object? And how can I do it with Array, can I parse the Array from the object as a String?

Comment: I think because it has an array there @MichailN..Maybe, but I am not sure! Glad that I helped.

Comment: The output in the text file from [saveAsTextFile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala) is simply calling the Object's toString method.  In this case Array.toString outputs like you had seen: [Ljava.lang.Object;@3b43c55